# Error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm just starting out and trying to predict a model I've previously trained

```
class EmotionRecognizer:

    def __init__(self, model_path, labels_mapping_path):
        self.model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_path)
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
        with open(labels_mapping_path, "rb") as f:
            mapper: MultiLabelBinarizer = pickle.load(f)
        
        self.type_map = {
            'input_ids': torch.long,
            'attention_mask': torch.float,
            'token_type_ids': torch.long,
            'labels': torch.float
        }
        self.le = mapper
        self.device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.model.to(self.device)
        self.model.eval()

    def recognize(self, text, treshold=0.5) -> str:
        predictions = self.get_raw_predictions(text, treshold)
        predictions = self.le.inverse_transform(predictions)
        prediction = list(predictions[0])
        texual_predictions = ", ".join(prediction)
        return texual_predictions

    def get_raw_predictions(self, text, treshold=0.5) -> np.ndarray:
      """
      Returns the normalized preditions of the model in binary format
      Normalized preditions are obtained by applying a sigmoid function to the raw preditions and then applying a treshold
      """
      if isinstance(text, str):
          encodings = self.tokenizer(text, add_special_tokens=True)
          encodings = {k: torch.tensor(v, dtype=self.type_map[k]).to(self.device) for k, v in encodings.items()}
      elif isinstance(text, list):
          encodings = self.tokenizer(text, add_special_tokens=True, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
          encodings = {k: v.to(self.device) for k, v in encodings.items()}

      with torch.no_grad():
          output = self.model(**encodings)
          predictions = torch.sigmoid(output.logits)
          predictions = torch.where(predictions > treshold, 1, 0)
          return predictions.detach().numpy()
```

the problem is that i try to predict a sentence with "get_raw_predictions" i get the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    972             raise ValueError("You have to specify either input_ids or inputs_embeds")
    973 
--> 974         batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
    975         device = input_ids.device if input_ids is not None else inputs_embeds.device
    976 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I really don't understand how I could fix it

Comment: your input is 1d, make sure to shape it correctly